# web3.js library not loading properly

Tags: web3js, nodejs, ethereumjs, installation, ethereumjs-tx

I am trying to load web3 library after installing it via command prompt. However, looks like it is not loading properly as it is not showing all the details for Ethereum ecosystem (ex. unitmap of various ether units).

============================================================================

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>node -v
v10.6.0

C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm -v
6.1.0

C:\WINDOWS\system32>node
```

> var Web3 = require('web3');
>   undefined
>
> Web3
>   { [Function: Web3]
>     providers:
>      { HttpProvider: [Function: HttpProvider],
>        IpcProvider: [Function: IpcProvider] } }
>
> var url = "https://mainnet.infura.io/pK8qXfQRfbImxGXdDPfC"
>   undefined
>
> var web3 = new Web3(url)
>   undefined
>
> var address = '0x281055Afc982d96fAB65b3a49cAc8b878184Cb16'
>   undefined
>
> web3.eth.getBalance(address, (err, bal) => {balance = bal})
>
> TypeError: this.provider.sendAsync is not a function
>       at RequestManager.sendAsync (C:\WINDOWS\system32\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\requestmanager.js:80:19)
>       at Eth.send [as getBalance] (C:\WINDOWS\system32\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\method.js:141:42)

============================================================================

First, I downloaded web3 via following command, after that I tried to load the library:

============================================================================
C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm install ethereum/web3.js --save
npm WARN system32@1.0.0 No description

## npm WARN system32@1.0.0 No repository field.

Is it happening because I haven't specified a repository while doing *"npm init"* command?

If it is helpful, I have provided the response as well for "npm init" command.

============================================================================

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.

See `npm help json` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg>` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
package name: (system32)
version: (1.0.0)
description:
git repository:
keywords:
author:
license: (ISC)
About to write to C:\WINDOWS\system32\package.json:

{
  "name": "system32",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "ganache-cli": "^6.1.5",
    "web3": "github:ethereum/web3.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}


Is this OK? (yes) yes
```

============================================================================

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you want `npm install web3`, not `npm install ethereum/web3.js`, but I suspect both work. Your first code snippet makes it look like web3 is indeed installed. Can you explain why you think something is wrong?

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code? (What provider are you using when you create your `web3` instance? E.g. `var web3 = new Web3(...)`

Comment: Just updated the original post with the rest of the code. Thanks.

Comment: I get the same error as you when I used `npm install ethereum/web3.js`, but I don't get that error if I use `npm install web3`.

Comment: what's the version of web3 that you've installed? 0.20.0 or 1.0.0 Beta? You can check using below javascript in the console.

 var version = web3.version.api;
 console.log(version);

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue with npm install web3. but after executed command of • npm install --global --production windows-build-tools, executing npm install web3 without error but when move into node console, require('web3') gets error. finally I found npm install web3 did not download web3.js and web3.min.js. but change to use npm install ethereum/web3.js works for me.

Answer (score 0):

To install web3, use `npm install web3`.

(I'm not entirely sure what `npm install ethereum/web3.js` is doing, but it seems to cause that error.)

Comment: Thanks @smarx for the reply. I tried to use "npm install web3" but am having the same error. I am not sure why is it working in your case and not in mine.

Comment: Make sure to start from a clean environment. (Delete the `node_modules` directory, or better yet just start from a brand new directory.)